# Passing data and state from filters as arguments Telegram bot

Tags: python, firebase-cloud-messaging, python-asyncio, telegram-bot

I am developing a bot for Telegram. Faced the problem of passing the user state from the filter to the function.
Ideally, I want to catch all messages from the user with any of his state, then run my_filter with arguments (message, state).
I will be grateful for help.

```
async def my_filter(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    return {'to': 11}

@dp.message_handler(my_filter, commands=['start22'], state='*')
async def my_message_handler(message: types.Message, to: int):
    await message.reply(f'to = {to}')
```

Error:

> TypeError: my_filter() missing 1 required positional argument: 'state'

p.s.
Tried putting `@dp.message_handler(state='*')` over `my_filter` --> `my_message_handler` is not firing